# JAVA playing sounds and unwanted overlay

Tags: java, audio, wav

Hello people of the internet.
I am trying to play sounds in my pexeso game, everytime player finds 2 of the kind, it should play a sound. The problem is (usually while playing the first sound of the session) that it plays the sound i want + like a half of another one at the same time (one over another)
the code:

```
public void zahraj (URL u)
    {
            AudioInputStream audio = null;

            try {
                audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(u);
            } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Clip clip=null;
            try {
                clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                clip.open(audio);
            } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            clip.start();
            }       
    }
```

I tried closing and flushing the stream, didnt work. I tried to make a new thread, everytime the method was called, didnt work either. Is there any simple solution?

Comment: why so many try catch? And you are probably threading it out incorectly

Comment: Eclipse wants me to take care of the exceptions and this is the easiest way for me. I tried to put whole code from the method to a new thread.